# Scroll to anchors

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, anchor

I'm trying to code a menu for my website that has the possibility to scroll to anchors on the same page and anchors on different pages.

The first one is working. The code is:

```
$(function() {
  $('a[href*=#]:not([href=#])').click(function() {
    if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') && location.hostname == this.hostname) {
      var target = $(this.hash);
      target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) +']');
      if (target.length) {
        $('html,body').animate({
          scrollTop: target.offset().top
        }, 1000);
        return false;
      }
    }
  });
});
```

The menu is the same on every page, I can't edit his code on each page. So the HTML code basically is:

```
<a id="mylink" href="http://www.mcsoftware.com.br/sitemc/#allcontentcontact"><span>Contato</span></a>
<a id="mylink2" href="http://www.mcsoftware.com.br/sitemc/#bluecontent"><span>Parceiros</span></a>
```

And I'm using javascript to detect if the user is on the homepage, and if he is, it changes the href behaviour, because it's only on the homepage that the anchors are on the same page of the menu. Look:

```
var url = "http://www.mcsoftware.com.br/sitemc/";
$(function(){
  if (location.href==url){
    $('#menu #mylink').attr("href","#allcontentcontact");
    $('#menu #mylink2').attr("href","#bluecontent");
  }
});
```

Now, the problem is the second part of what I've said on the beginning of the post: Scroll to anchors on different pages. 
So, what script should I use to do the trick and doesn't affect everything that I've already done? Is it possible?
(And the code need to hide the "#nameoftheanchor" from the URL, like the first code already do)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I did something that is working really well! But still shows the "#anchortag" on the URL when the anchor is on another page.

```
<script>
var url = "http://www.mcsoftware.com.br/sitemc/";
if (location.href==url) {
$(function() {
  $('a[href*=#]:not([href=#])').click(function() {
    if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') && location.hostname == this.hostname) {
      var target = $(this.hash);
      target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) +']');
      if (target.length) {
        $('html,body').animate({
          scrollTop: target.offset().top
        }, 1000);
        return false;
      }
    }
  });
});
} else {
var jump=function(e)
{
   if (e){
       e.preventDefault();
       var target = $(this).attr("href");
   }else{
       var target = location.hash;
   }

   $('html,body').animate(
   {
       scrollTop: $(target).offset().top
   },2000,function()
   {
       location.hash = target;
   });

}

$('html, body').hide();

$(document).ready(function()
{
    $('a[href^=#]').bind("click", jump);

    if (location.hash){
        setTimeout(function(){
            $('html, body').scrollTop(0).show();
            jump();
        }, 0);
    }else{
        $('html, body').show();
    }
});
}
</script>
```

any help?

Answer (score 0):

To answer your second question, the browsing history can be changed using

`window.history.pushState()` and 
`window.history.replaceState()`.

For how to use each function, see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history

`window.location.pathname` will retrieve the current url path. So combining these concepts, I came up with the following:

```
history.pushState("", "", window.location.pathname);
```

This should remove the hash while keeping the rest of the url in-tact. If this doesn't solve your problem, hopefully it will at least get you started on the right *path*.

Comment: it hides the hash, but doesn't work. because it doesn't jump to the anchor.
i just go back to the homepage.
thanks for the reply!

Comment: The code in your answer looks like it already correctly jumps to the anchor. If you want to use that code, then simply remove the line that updates the url hash. In other words, just remove the line that reads 

"location.hash = target;" If that doesn't work, than I don't think I fully understand the problem. :)